# How to configure apache nutch to remove all a tags and it's content?

Tags: apache, configuration, nutch

Is this even possible?

I'm having problem with navigation that is also included in to the documents as a content. So that's why I want to remove all link tags so that it isn't in the data.

I'm using the 1.7 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only wanted to tell nutch to not follow the "a" tags you could simply add "a" to the "parser.html.outlinks.ignore_tags" setting.

If you want to remove "a" tags and their contents from parsed data, since the current HtmlParser shipped with nutch does not have any setting related to this, I think you should write a nutch plugin and develop a HtmlParseFilter that do your logic.